# X-Ray Diffraction for Crystal Structures

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-rays

So I was carrying out an XRD experiment and found that I only got peaks for the (2 0 0) and (4 0 0) lattice structures. I was wondering why there aren't any peaks for the (1 0 0) and (3 0 0) lattice planes for the crystals? I was trying to get my head around what I can learn about the crystal structure but the only thing I can think of is that it only consists of even planes and that is why peaks are observed at (2 0 0) and (4 0 0). Cheers :)

Comment: Do 100 and 300 planes have an angle that would yield a whole number of wavelengths?

Comment: Only simple cubic crystals exhibit every diffraction peak. BCC and FCC crystals don't because of interference effects. Google "diffraction selection rules" for some lectures on it.